# Forever loop in Blender scripting?

Tags: python, redis, blender

If you add

```py
while True:
    print("hi")
```

to an otherwise functional script in Blender's scripting window and run it, Blender hangs.

This is undesirable because I'm trying to use Redis as a pub-sub broker, such that another script can send positions for Blender to display:

```py
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(radius=0.005, location=(0, 0, 0))
ball = bpy.context.object
ball.name = 'sphere'


for message in pubsub.listen():
    if message['type'] == 'message':
        position_str = message['data'].decode('utf-8')
        position = ast.literal_eval(position_str)
        print(f"Received position: {position}")
        ball.location = position
```

This forever loop also hangs Blender and doesn't move the ball as I want.

Is there any way to get this to work?

Update:

I tried doing it in a subprocess, it no longer hangs but it doesn't create a sphere either:

```py
def update_sphere_from_redis():
    r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
    pubsub = r.pubsub()
    pubsub.subscribe('positions')
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(radius=0.005, location=(0, 0, 0))

    ball = bpy.context.object
    ball.name = 'sphere'
    for message in pubsub.listen():
        if message['type'] == 'message':
            position_str = message['data'].decode('utf-8')
            position = ast.literal_eval(position_str)
            print(f"Received position: {position}")
            ball.location = position
    



process = multiprocessing.Process(target=update_sphere_from_redis)
    
# Start the processB
process.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using a queue and a timer: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.timers.html. The function in a thread runs forever and adds to a queue, the function that gets called by a timer reads from the queue:

```py
import bpy
import numpy as np
import redis
import random
import queue
import time
import threading
import ast

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(radius=0.01, location=(0, 0, 1))
ball = bpy.context.object
ball.name = 'sphere'

location_queue = queue.Queue()

r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
pubsub = r.pubsub()
pubsub.subscribe('positions')
    
def read_redis_to_queue():
    for message in pubsub.listen():
        if message['type'] == 'message':
            position_str = message['data'].decode('utf-8')
            position = ast.literal_eval(position_str)
            location_queue.put((position))


def use_locations_from_queue():
    while not location_queue.empty():
        location = location_queue.get()
        ball.location = location
        ball.name = str(location[2])
        bpy.context.view_layer.update()
    return 0.01


bpy.app.timers.register(use_locations_from_queue)
my_thread = threading.Thread(target=read_redis_to_queue)
my_thread.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Blender scripts execute on the same interpreter as the UI (check out [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/153432) and the relevant [blender docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_overview.html) for more information) meaning that blender will wait for whatever script is running to finish before continuing which in the case of an infinite loop will freeze blender's UI.

I don't know much about blender scripting but if you want to know where to start when looking to implement your script, I suggest you look into python modules like [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) and [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html). [This](https://blenderartists.org/t/blender2-93-pyqt-async/1329959) seems like a good post to start looking into.

EDIT: To give you some examples more specific to your issue:

- [Async/Await Basics in Python with Redis](https://redis.com/blog/async-await-programming-basics-python-examples/)
- [Asyncio Examples with Redis](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/asyncio_examples.html)

Comment: The linked post is very complicated and I'm not sure if it solves my problem (updating the position of items in the scene)

Comment: The linked post is an example of asynchronous scripting in Blender, which is what you're trying to do with your current system. Admittedly, the details of the example are not relevant to your question so I've edited my answer and added some links relevant to the question of accessing a Redis database asynchronously in Python but they're not specific to Blender. You can look into them or try one of the strategies in the other answers.